# Password Widget and Password Hashing in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new in Python coding and now trying to learn Django. 
Right now i am using django 1.11.3 version.
So i have learned the basic thing in Django and created an app.

In my app, i have created a student model which include an password field. What i have noticed is, in Admin module password field is stored in simple text. So i need help to hash the password field in admin module. I need md5 hashing.

So can u guys help me. Is there any method to solve this?

This is what i have tried.

My Model

```
class student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    dob = models.DateField()
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My Admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import student

admin.site.register(student)

class studentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        student.password: {'widget': forms.PasswordInput},
        }
```

Comment: post your view, how you are saving the password. you have nothing to do in admin, the password will be hashed and will be shown in admin panel

Comment: I think the field showing in the admin panel are based on the model created. Right?

Comment: yes but in django there is nothing like password field so the hashed password is also been in normal text but hashed

Comment: Is there a reason you can't extend Django's User model? All this will be sorted for you.

Answer (score 3):

You **must not** do this.

Django includes an authentication framework that has everything you need already, including the ability to [customise the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) to include your date of birth field.

(Note, there is no point including age as well; you can always calculate that from the dob when you need it.)

Answer (score 2):

A great place to see how this is done is to look at the Django source code in django.contrib.auth, they handle this same scenario for a User.

The idea is that you would use a custom admin form with a password field so that you can get the raw password from the form and then manually set the password running it through a hasher first.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class Student(models.Model):

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)
```

The make_password also takes a hasher type arguement if you don't want to use the default one.

Comment: Though I am 100% in agreement with Daniel here, try to use the built in Django User and customize as necessary.